# How to scaffold a new project with TailwindCSS, PostCSS and Alpine.js using Vite

Tags: tailwind-css, vite, postcss, alpine.js

I want scaffold a new project with TailwindCSS, PostCSS and Alpine.js using Vite.
And when I follow the document ( https://vitejs.dev/guide/ ) to create the project, it always ask me to specify the template ( vue, react ... ), but I do not want it.

Is it possible to use vite to scaffold the project TailwindCSS, PostCSS and Alpine.js ( module not CDN link ) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for Vanilla. You can select Vanilla as framework.
`npm create vite@latest my-app` then select **Vanilla**.Vanilla means plain Javascript.

"Vanilla JavaScript" is a term used by developers to describe ordinary JavaScript. It defines the use of built-in JavaScript methods and objects without additional frameworks or libraries.

Comment: I'm new to all this, You’re a lifesaver !!! @MaikLowrey